# How to read azure wiki by using API in python script?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

How I can read **azure wiki** by using **python script**.

I tried to use API for Azure wiki
and the API is :

GET [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wiki/wikis/{wikiIdentifier}?api-version=6.0](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/wiki/wikis/%7BwikiIdentifier%7D?api-version=6.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean calling the REST API using python script, then you can reference the following example:

You need to create a PAT first, see [Create a PAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows#create-a-pat).

```
import requests
import base64

pat = 'tcd******************************tnq'
authorization = str(base64.b64encode(bytes(':'+pat, 'ascii')), 'ascii')

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic '+authorization
}

response = requests.get(
    url="https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wiki/wikis/{wikiIdentifier}?api-version=6.0", headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```